# Double Bracket [[]] within a Function

Tags: r

Q.  Write a function called col_median() that takes one argument df and returns the vector of column medians.

```
col_median <- function(df) {
    output <- vector("double", ncol(df))
    for (i in seq_along(df)) {
        output[[i]] <- median(df[[i]])
    }
    output
}
```

While working on this problem, I was using the following line of code that doesn’t work. Can someone kindly explain why?
 output[i] <- median (df[i])

Answer (score 1):

The double bracket selects a single element in a list or data.frame (as data.frame is also a list, so the columns are elements). Here, we are assigning the median of each column of 'df' to an output list. As we are defining a `list` 'output', it should be

```
col_median <- function(df) {
 output <- vector("list", ncol(df))
 for (i in seq_along(df)) {
    output[[i]] <- median(df[[i]])
   }
 output
}

col_median(df) #this returns a `list` output
```

The OP's function returns a `vector`.

If we are using

```
 output[i] <- median(df[i])
```

by defining,

```
output <- vector("double", ncol(df))
```

the lhs of `<-` is fine, but `df[i]` returns a `data.frame` and `median` would not work on that.  Instead it should `median(df[[i]])` to extract the column as a `vector`.

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:9, 10*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
```

Comment: @thelatemail You are right about that, but I am answering the `[[` part

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I'm a newbie. Please elaborate more by giving an example if possible, when you say, "...... df[i] returns a data.frame and median would not work on that. Thanks again.

Comment: That's is little hard to follow. Thanks again.